# redirect without storing in history

Tags: javascript

I am redirecting a webpage using `location.replace("someurl");` but this implies a history of navigation (previous URL) stored.

How to redirect without storing the previous URL in the browser's history. Is it even possible ?

Thanks

Comment: `location.replace` will not store the url in the history, just like you did

Comment: NO, because the back button in the browser is still showing.

Comment: It's still showing but you can't navigate to the previous page that made the `location.replace` - I just tested it and it works

Comment: Yes, but that's to be considered a bug if you can't return to the page on back button click. the button back shouldn't show up in this case.

Comment: If you go on any website there is always a back button. If you clicked the back button it would just return to the new tab screen.

Comment: @Spectric i don't get your example.

Comment: Visit `google.com`. You see a back button.